# laravel download response filename not changing

Tags: laravel, filenames

I am using laravel and trying to download a file and change the filename.
The documentation tells me that I can use the second argument as the new filename, but the filename won't change to "testdownload.zip" somehow. What am I doing wrong?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads

```
    // routes
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function()
    {
        Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function()
        {
            Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:root|admin|store|user']], 
function()
            {
                // download purchase
                Route::get('dashboard/order/downloadfile', [
                    'as'    => 'order-download',
                    'uses'  => 'Post\PostController@download'
                ]);
            });
        }
    }

    // method in Controller
    public function download(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip'), 'testdownload.zip', ['Content-Type: application/zip']);
    }
```

When I do dd(response()->download(storage_path('app/lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip'), 'testdownload.zip', ['Content-Type: application/zip'])) the following is returned (could it be the perms / permissions 0100666? I am on Windows):

```
BinaryFileResponse {#449 ▼
  #file: File {#464 ▼
    path: "C:\xampp71\htdocs\storage\app"
    filename: "lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip"
    basename: "lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip"
    pathname: "C:\xampp71\htdocs\storage\app/lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip"
    extension: "zip"
    realPath: "C:\xampp71\htdocs\storage\app\lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip"
    aTime: 2019-11-14 11:34:52
    mTime: 2019-11-14 11:34:52
    cTime: 2019-11-01 16:05:10
    inode: 0
    size: 24626
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\xampp71\htdocs\storage\app\lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip"
  }
  #offset: 0
  #maxlen: -1
  #deleteFileAfterSend: false
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#234 ▼
    #computedCacheControl: array:1 [▼
      "public" => true
    ]
    #cookies: []
    #headerNames: array:5 [▼
      0 => 0
      "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
      "date" => "Date"
      "last-modified" => "Last-Modified"
      "content-disposition" => "Content-Disposition"
    ]
    #headers: array:5 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▶]
      "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
      "date" => array:1 [▶]
      "last-modified" => array:1 [▶]
      "content-disposition" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "attachment; filename=testdownload.zip"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: array:1 [▼
      "public" => true
    ]
  }
  #content: null
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: dd(response()->download(storage_path('app/lorem-ipsum-shop-1.zip'), 'testdownload.zip', ['Content-Type: application/zip']));; please check.

Comment: so you want to change your file name when you download file m i right>?

Comment: @VikasKatariya the downloaded filename should be different from the original filename on the server

Answer (score 0):

Always clear your cache... I think it stores the filename before the renaming.